# Converting field under pandas column from str to dict and creating new column

Tags: python, pandas, object

I have a pandas column called **geo** inside a dataFrame called **df**. It can be populated or not.

**geo** has an object, referencing an id of a place.

I'm acessing row 18 using `df.iloc[18].geo` and it returns:

```py
"{'place_id': '1c37515518593fe3'}"
```

its a **str** type.

How i can create a new column inside **df** called **place_id** countaining the value (on my example: *1c37515518593fe3*) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post should help you convert string literals into dictionaries:
[Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

EDIT updated for possible null values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["{'place_id': '1c37515518593fe3'}", np.NaN], columns=["geo"])
df["geo"] = df["geo"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x) if not pd.isnull(x) else x)
df['place_id'] = df['geo'].apply(lambda x: x.get('place_id', np.NaN) if not pd.isnull(x) else x)
print(df)

                                geo          place_id
0  {'place_id': '1c37515518593fe3'}  1c37515518593fe3
1                               NaN               NaN
```